# Change Visual State On PropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

Is it possible to add a behaviour in Blend to switch to a different visual state in response to a property changed event on a binding? It would need to switch to this state for a few seconds and then back out.

I'm trying to change the background colour of a control everytime a count value on the datacoontext changes. I've tried using a GoToStateAction and EventTrigger/DataTrigger but can't quite get the trigger setup right - I suspect that I need to approach this in a different way but I'm not sure how.
Any help would be appreciated -

Here is the xaml for the border - I'm stuck on how to set up the trigger to change the visual state - I want to switch to BrightState for a few seconds and back to NormalState everytime the Value of Count on the viewmodel changes

```
<Border x:Name="border" Grid.Row="2" Background="CadetBlue">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock><Run Text="Count:"/></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Count}" MinWidth="30">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <!--<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="textBlock">
                        <ei:GoToStateAction/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>-->
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

Here are the visual states defined to change the background colour of the border:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FlickerStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="NormalState"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="BrightState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF6CD9DC"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: what control do you use?

Comment: @StepUp I'm trying to change the background of a border when the property changes. I've set up a visual state for the new colour, I just don't know how to make it go into this state

Comment: are you sure that you see OnPropertyChanged event in Border?

Comment: No, this event is not listed if I select an EventTrigger on the GoToStateAction. DataTrigger doesn't seem to be the right option either as it looks to be comparing the value of a binding to a value that you specify which isn't quite what I want either.

Comment: please post some code. It is very complicated what it is necessary.

Comment: I'd bet you could just do `RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated"` as your eventtrigger and just add `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` to your TextBlock binding base even if you don't notify otherwise and basically keep what you got there.